# Any way to get a url as a subpage to a subpage on Google Sites?

Tags: google, google-sites

As above. Essentially Google Sites seems limited in that you can only have a URL redirect as a sublink to a subpage and not another URL redirect on Google Sites. I was wondering if there was a workaround for this?

Comment: I don't have a lot of experience with Google sites, so I don't know the answer to this question.  But when I tried Google sites, I found it very limiting.  In general you don't have a lot of control over your URLs, redirects, status codes, or HTML code.   You'd think Google would build a website hosting product with more attention to features that make it easier for their search engines to index.